# autodiscover multiple SMTP namespaces

Tags: iis-7, exchange-2007, autodiscovery

I'm about to tune our autodiscover-config. For our main-domain it works perfectly.
Now I'm about to add support for multiple domains.

In this [article](http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/exchange-autodiscover.html) Jaap Wesselius describes how to add an additional virtual directory with an http-redirection to our main-domain-autodiscover-virtual-directory. He uses a 2nd IP-address for this but didn't mention **why** he is using a 2nd IP-address.

My question is: couldn't I just create a new virtual-directory in the default web site with the same IP for the redirect? What's the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason has to do with the SSL certificate.  It is unlikely that you want to purchase an SSL cert for all "autodiscover." SMTP domains you host.  Using a second IP address gives you the ability to create a separate website that does not use SSL.

So your second autodiscover url would be:

- http://autodiscover.domain2.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml.

The autodiscover.xml would then be set to redirect to:

- https://autodiscover.mainsmtpdomain.com/autodiscover/autdiscover.xml

This way you only need an SSL cert for autodiscover.mainsmtpdomain.com.

When searching for the autodiscover service a client will follow the following in this setup scenario for your Second SMTP domain:

1. Tries https://domain2.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml (Fails)
2. Tries https://autodiscover.domain2.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml (Fails)
3. Tries **http**://autodiscover.domain2.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml (succeeds)

   - Gets redirected to https://autodiscover.mainsmtpdomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

If the third option were to fail it would go on to look for SRV records (_autodiscover._tcp.mainsmtp.com)

You can not add a new virtual directory to the CAS default website to accomplish this.  This is because you would then have two "autodiscover" virtual directories in the same site.

You could create a new site on the CAS and use the above outlined steps to accomplish this.  However, this also would require you to set the default website to use a specific IP and add an additional IP to your CAS NIC for the new site.  See the Autodiscover Whitepaper:  [Scenario 4](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332063%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx#Scenario4HowTo)

Comment: I understood that I need this to forward to my ssl-autodiscover-site from my maindomain (because http-forwarding is not available with ssl). That's ok. But can't I just create a http virtual directory in my default web site which redirects to my maindomain-autodiscover? (I think I misunderstood IIS ;))

Comment: See Edits above

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I got it now. I'm used to apache-virtual-directorys, which can look at the subdomain that has been used and 'route' the use to a specific real directory... But it is possible to let a normal (linux) web-server do the redirection-work (it holds the same maindomain)?

Comment: I'd imagine you would be able to, although I have not done this.  The client is going to be looking for the directory structure of /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml.  So as long as it can find the autodiscover.xml file and the file properly redirects, it should work.